What's "go" mean in "something that goes to the essence of a man’s conscience"? (SPOILERS FOR THE BOOK To Kill a Mockingbird AHEAD!!!)
In the book To Kill a Mockingbird a part of the plotline is an upcoming court trial of a black man. His defense attorney is a father of two who is talking about the future case with his young daughter. Most people in town are not pleased with him defending this man. He says to her:

This case, Tom Robinson’s case, is something that goes to the essence
of a man’s conscience—Scout, I couldn’t go to church and worship God
if I didn’t try to help that man.”

I don't understand what "go" means in this context. The only definition I could find that fits is:
(intransitive) To belong (somewhere).
Synonyms: belong, have a place
My shirts go on this side of the wardrobe.
This piece of the jigsaw goes on the other side. (Wiktionary)

Your third
paragraph asks about 'get'; it should be 'go/ goes'.

I think it's about 64 years too late to worry about spoilers for that book!

The mockingbird dies!

Collins Dictionary sense 15 for go
says

If something goes into something else, it is put in it as one of the parts or elements that form it.

In the OP’s quoted paragraph, the
defense attorney was telling his daughter that taking up that case was crucial, as if his conscience or that of anyone in that situation
would be incomplete without it.
go

When you used "take up" in your answer while saying "was telling his daughter that taking up that case was crucial" did you mean it in this sense: accept an offer or challenge.
"most residents took up the offer of refurbished equipment"
Similar:
accept
say yes to
agree to
accede to
adopt
get

Also, is this the same sense of "go" in the common collocation "it goes to the very heart of..."?

Identical meaning. The two phrases are perfectly synonymous.    One cannot claim to be a man of conscience yet fail to hecome involved in the matter.  The situation, in going to the heart or essence, is so clear that there's no wafflng on the matter. As in the Talking Heads lyric, "a straight line exists between me and the good thing. I have seen that line and its direction is known to me."

@Static Bounce, yes, taking up that case means accepting it.  Your understanding of go is right  too.
TimR explained it well.
